# How to select 11 best players from a list of players in python?

Tags: python, list, random

I am trying to create a program where I should be able to randomly select 11 players from 4 lists of players. Here is what I have tried.

```
import random
                                                                   # PLayers   Min   Max
                                                                   # ---------------------
wk = ['Rahul', 'Siefiet']                                          # wk         1     4
batsman = ['Rohit', 'Iyer', 'Munro', 'Pandey', 'Guptil', 'Taylor'] # batsman    3     6
bowler = ['Bumrah', 'Southee', 'Chahal', 'Sodhi', 'Dube']          # bowler     3     6
allRounder = ['jadeja', 'Santer', 'Dube']                          # allrounder 1     4
counter = 0

bat = random.randint(3, 6)
allr = random.randint(1, 4)
print(bat)

while counter != 11:
    for a in range(bat):
        print("Batsman:", set(random.choice(batsman)))
        counter += bat #adding random generated number to counter
    for a in range(bat):
        print("Bowler", set(random.choice(bowler)))
        counter += bat
    for a in range(allr):
        print("Allrounder:", set(random.choice(allRounder)))
        counter += allr
    for a in range(allr):
        print("Allrounder:", set(random.choice(wk)))
        counter += allr
```

When I try to run it. It goes to an infinite loop, Here is a screenshot.

[image]

Here is something I want to add to this.

```
if the randomly generated value for the batsman is 6 then 3 bowlers 1 all-rounder 1 wk
if the randomly generated value for the (batsman is 5) then (3 or 4 bowlers), (1 or 2 all-rounder depending upon if 3 bowlers are opted then 2 all rounders if 4 bowlers are opted then 1 allrounder), (1 or 2 wk depending upon if 2 AR are opted then 1 wk if 1 AR is opted then 2 wk)
And Many more conditions Like This
```

Any Idea how can I implement it???

Comment: I am not sure what your code is supposed to do, but the first thing to do to avoid an infinite loop is to change `while counter != 11:` by `while counter < 11:`

Comment: @AlWld Changing '!=' to '<'  stops from going to an infinite loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to causing an infinite loop, the `while` loop does not guarantee you will get exactly 11 players each time. Here is another way you can do it. Shuffle each list, and add the minimum number of players from each list to a new list `chosen`. This starts you off with 8 players. Then combine and shuffle the remaining players from all 4 lists, and add 3 more. Now you've got 11 randomly chosen players with the requirements you set, and you can use a dictionary to print them according to category.

```
wk = ['Rahul', 'Siefiet']
batsman = ['Rohit', 'Iyer', 'Munro', 'Pandey', 'Guptil', 'Taylor']
bowler = ['Bumrah', 'Southee', 'Chahal', 'Sodhi', 'Dube']
allRounder = ['jadeja', 'Santer']

random.shuffle(batsman)
random.shuffle(bowler)
random.shuffle(allRounder)
random.shuffle(wk)

chosen = batsman[:3] + bowler[:3] + allRounder[:1] + wk[:1]
remainder = batsman[3:] + bowler[3:] + allRounder[1:] + wk[1:]
random.shuffle(remainder)
chosen.extend(remainder[:3])

players = {'Batsman': [x for x in chosen if x in batsman],
           'Bowler': [x for x in chosen if x in bowler],
           'AllRounder': [x for x in chosen if x in allRounder],
           'Wk': [x for x in chosen if x in wk]}

for key in players:
    for name in players[key]:
        print(f'{key}: {name}')
```

Comment: Thanks, @alec for the response, Can you please explain that what exactly the remainder in doing??

Comment: Remainder is a list with all the players that were not put in chosen. It is simply shuffled before 3 more players are selected from it, to get to 11.

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to create a program where I should be able to randomly
>   select 11 players from 4 lists of players

you can use [random.sample](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample):

```
import random

final = []
min_to_extract = [1, 3, 4, 3]
for m , l in zip(min_to_extract, (wk, batsman, bowler, allRounder)):
    index_to_extract = random.sample(range(len(l)), m)
    final.extend([l[i] for i in index_to_extract])

    l[:] = [e for i, e in enumerate(l) if i not in index_to_extract]


final.extend(random.sample([*wk, *batsman, *bowler, *allRounder], 11 - len(final)))

random.shuffle(final)
```

**output:**

```
['Rohit',
 'Dube',
 'Guptil',
 'Chahal',
 'Pandey',
 'Santer',
 'jadeja',
 'Southee',
 'Siefiet',
 'Bumrah',
 'Dube']
```

Comment: There are certain conditions like minimum batsman/bowler must be 3. It doesn't match any conditions